# Package installer crash on install LG Optimus when installing my application

Tags: android, launcher

When I run my application in the emulator, it runs fine.  When I send it (email) to my phone, the following message occurs:

Sorry! The application Package Installer (process.com.android.packageinstaller) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

I have tried the solutions to similar questions on SO and have looked through Google to find a solution that will work, so far to no avail.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="application.android"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0"
  android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">        
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HistoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DiagnosisActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>      
    <activity android:name=".eula"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>      
    <activity android:name=".disclaimer"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>    
    <activity android:name=".DetailsActivity"
        android:label ="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>        
    <activity android:name=".ResultsActivity"
        android:label ="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>        
    <activity android:name=".DiagnosisNoteActivity"
        android:label ="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>        
    <activity android:name=".NewDiagnosisActivity"
        android:label ="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>      
    <activity android:name=".DiagnosisTabActivityGroup"
        android:label ="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>        
    <activity android:name=".TabGroupActivity"
        android:label ="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>        
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label ="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>       
    <activity android:name=".NewScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>
</application>
```

When debugging on my phone through Eclipse the following shows in console:

```
[2012-03-12 23:38:52 - ruleout] Android Launch!
[2012-03-12 23:38:52 - ruleout] adb is running normally.
[2012-03-12 23:38:52 - ruleout] Performing ruleout.android.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-03-12 23:38:54 - ruleout] Uploading ruleout.apk onto device 'A0000028F2ABCF'
[2012-03-12 23:39:11 - ruleout] Installing ruleout.apk...
[2012-03-12 23:40:16 - ruleout] Success!
[2012-03-12 23:40:16 - ruleout] Starting activity ruleout.android.MainActivity on device A0000028F2ABCF
[2012-03-12 23:40:17 - ruleout] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=ruleout.android/.MainActivity }
[2012-03-12 23:40:17 - ruleout] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=ruleout.android/.MainActivity } from null (pid=16174, uid=2000) requires android.permission.INTERNET
```

There is nothing shown in the LogCat window and as far as I can tell, I have enabled internet permissions.  Also, I did add the android:debuggable="true" attribute to the application tag.

Comment: can you check the logcat while installing the package to get more details ? Usually that contains info about the exact error the OS is throwing

Comment: Hope you have added all required permissions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem so for anyone who comes across the same issue, if you remove the android:permission attribute from the application tag in the manifest, then it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Are you debugging? If so, you will need to add "android:debuggable" your application tag like so:

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true"
```

You should also check that the phone is in debug mode (Settings>Application>Debugging)